# Elastic APM - RUM JS Agent: Integration with React-Redux applications

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, kibana, apm, rum

Are there any npm modules/plugins exists so as integrate Elastic APM's RUM JS Agent with the application ?

By integration i mean good coupling with application so as to record all the things /events(such as route loading, all service requests, actions etc.) and provide it to elastic search.

Answer (score 2):

As it is reported on the official site it could be released in the future.

> Some of the features we are very excited to provide in the near future
>   include distributed tracing and providing framework-specific
>   information (e.g., route change times) for some of the frontend
>   frameworks such as React, Angular, Vue.js, etc.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/elastic-apm-rum-js-agent-is-generally-available

For now you can rely on Elastic APM RUM JS Agent using JS tags:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/js-base/3.x/getting-started.html#using-script-tags